# Faster code for 'distinct' on lists

Tags: scala, optimization, code-generation, isabelle

*This question refers to code generation with the Isabelle/HOL theorem prover.*

When I export code for the `distinct` function on lists

```
export_code distinct in Scala file -
```

I get the following code

```
def member[A : HOL.equal](x0: List[A], y: A): Boolean = (x0, y) match {
  case (Nil, y) => false
  case (x :: xs, y) => HOL.eq[A](x, y) || member[A](xs, y)
}

def distinct[A : HOL.equal](x0: List[A]): Boolean = x0 match {
  case Nil => true
  case x :: xs => ! (member[A](xs, x)) && distinct[A](xs)
}
```

This code has quadratic runtime. Is there a faster version available? I think of something like importing `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char"` for strings at the beginning of my theory and efficient code generation for lists is set up.
A better implementation for `distinct` would be to sort the list in O(n log n) and iterate over the list once. But I guess one can do better?

Anyway, is there a faster implementation for `distinct` and maybe other functions from `Main` available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know of any faster implementation in Isabelle2013's library, but you can easily do it yourself as follows:

1. Implement a function `distinct_sorted` that determines distinctness on sorted lists.
2. Prove that `distinct_sorted` indeed implements `distinct` on sorted lists
3. Prove a lemma that implements `distinct` via `distinct_list` and sorting, and declare it as the new code equation for `distinct`.

In summary, this looks as follows:

```
context linorder begin
fun distinct_sorted :: "'a list => bool" where
  "distinct_sorted [] = True"
| "distinct_sorted [x] = True"
| "distinct_sorted (x#y#xs) = (x ~= y & distinct_sorted (y#xs))"

lemma distinct_sorted: "sorted xs ==> distinct_sorted xs = distinct xs"
  by(induct xs rule: distinct_sorted.induct)(auto simp add: sorted_Cons)
end

lemma distinct_sort [code]: "distinct xs = distinct_sorted (sort xs)"
 by(simp add: distinct_sorted)
```

Next, you need an efficient sorting algorithm. By default, `sort` uses insertion sort. If you import Multiset from HOL/Library, `sort` will be implemented by quicksort. If you import [Efficient Mergesort](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Efficient-Mergesort.shtml) from the Archive of Formal Proofs, you get merge sort.

While this can improve efficiency, there's also a snag: After the above declarations, you can execute `distinct` only on lists whose elements are instances of the type class `linorder`. As this refinement happens only inside the code generator, your definitions and theorems in Isabelle are not affected.

For example, to apply `distinct` to a list of lists in any code equation, you first have to define a linear order on lists: `List_lexord` in `HOL/Library` does so by picking the lexicographic order, but this requires a linear order on the elements. If you want to use `string`, which abbreviates `char list`, `Char_ord` defines the usual order on `char`. If you map characters to the character type of the target language with `Code_Char`, you also need the adaptation theory `Code_Char_ord` for the combination with `Char_ord`.

Comment: And [this mailing list post](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2011-March/msg00012.html) describes how I can tell isabelle that a `string` is a `linorder`. Now, `distinct [''a'', ''b'']` works fine.

Comment: complete dump of [Efficient_Distinct](http://pastebin.com/1PvBgVeE) file and the corresponding [Scala code](http://pastebin.com/6Bx4ieS2)

Comment: To make `string` a `linorder` instance, just import List_lexord and Char_ord from HOL/Library. Char_ord provides the linear order for `nibble` and `char`.

Comment: You also need the adaptation theory `Code_Char_ord` from HOL/Library for the combination `Code_Char` and `Char_ord`

Comment: Works :) Could you please edit your post and summarize our comment discussion? I now import `List_lexord`, `Product_ord`, `Code_Char`, `Code_Char_chr`, and `Code_Char_ord`.